Android google chrome prints letters before keydown event
In Android Google Chrome (I'm using 128.0.6613.127 version) with javascript I've bound event callbacks
addEvent(elm, 'keydown', onKeyDown);
addEvent(elm, 'input', onInput);

Letter is already printed before the callback unlike other browsers.
How to callback before the letter printing.

Adding couple more events then it works in mobile with softkeyboard also
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

function preventInput(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    const randomLetter = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 97);

  event.target.value = randomLetter;
}


inputElement.addEventListener('keydown', preventInput);
inputElement.addEventListener('keypress', preventInput);
inputElement.addEventListener('input', preventInput);
inputElement.addEventListener('beforeinput', preventInput);


but it seems noway of obtaining keyCode

yes there is event.data
